# cocos2dX Orientation Support

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I am having this problem when doing a simple orientation test.

Suppose I am using a design resolution of 480*320 for landscape and 320*480 for portrait mode.
Now I have a long sprite of width 480 which doesn't show all of itself in portrait mode.
Then upon orientation change, I reposition it so that it should show properly.
After doing so, I successfully place the sprite correctly, anchoring at the bottom left corner, but the sprite still doesn't fully show itself.

http://tinypic.com/r/34e45c2/8   <- portrait mode
http://tinypic.com/r/2s84vgh/8   <- landscape after repositioning

Steps to reproduce:

1) create a default project with the create_project tool

2) Edit RootViewController.mm as follow
add these 3 lines to    didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:**(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation**

```
auto dum = Director::getInstance()->getRunningScene()->getChildByTag(13579)
                 ->getChildByTag(24680);
dum->setPosition(cocos2d::Point::ZERO);
dum->setAnchorPoint(cocos2d::Point::ZERO);
```

}

3) add the tags used above,
      under createScene change to 
    `scene->addChild(layer, 0, 13579);`
      under HelloWorld::init
    `this->addChild(sprite, 0, 24680);`

4) under project setting "General" tab, tick all 4 modes under "Device Orientation"

5) run in simulator and then click Hardware->rotateLeft

How may I fix this problem?
[I have tried changing the HelloWorld layer's content size to getFrameSize() as well with no luck.]

Thanks.

PS I am using cocos2dx-3.0alpha1

Comment: I just figured out what's going wrong after some trial and error.
The EGLView and the winSize should also be updated.

adding the following lines fixed the problem
    `auto v = Director::getInstance()->getOpenGlView();
     v->setFrameSize(s.width, s.height);
     v->setDesignResolutionSize(s.width, s.height, ResolutionPolicy::FIXED_HEIGHT);`

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding the following code in your AppDelegate.cpp in your AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching() methode :

```
 glview->setDesignResolutionSize(320,480,ResolutionPolicy::SHOW_ALL);
```

Worked for me. I hope it helps.